# How to use sessions on the database.php file

Tags: php, database, cakephp

What I would want to do is to switch between development_db and local_db.
in the index page, there is a list of databases that i can choose from if i click a database name on the list, the whole app will change to that specific database that i choose.
What I did was, I set a session variable in my controller that will be read when the database.php loads up, but my problem is that I can't use

```
$this->Session->read();
```

on the database.php file. is there a way that the database.php file can read my session variables?

Comment: Sessions are user-specific, it doesn't seem right to potentially switch DBs for each user. Would you consider a different method? Instead, define a `TESTING` constant in your config, and simply read the value of that constant (`if (TESTING)`) to determine which database connection to open.

Comment: How is database.php included and what is `$this` supposed to refer to?

Comment: what your trying to say is that ill define a constant variable on the database.php file? and how would i change that constant variable in the controller?

Comment: the $this->Session->read(); refers to the database name that will be used in connection to the database.

Comment: This [article](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/stevena0/2010/08/29/use-different-configs-for-different-environments) may be useful to you (although it's based on an older version of Cake, you should be able to adapt the methodology into what you're trying to do).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Cake's `Configure::write()` / `Configure::read()` in your Controller, then access it in the `database.php` file - something like this:

```
//controller
Configure::write('DEV', true);

//database
function __construct() {
    $dev = Configure::read('DEV');
    if($dev)  $this->default = $this->dev;
}

function DATABASE_CONFIG() {
    $this->__construct();
}
```

**Another option:**

The other way (the way we currently do it) is to check for `$_SERVER['DEV']`.  Just set it in your `httpd-vhosts.conf` file (if using wamp):

```
<VirtualHost mysite>
    DocumentRoot C:\wamp\www\mysite
    ServerName mysite
    SetEnv DEV 1
</VirtualHost>
```

This is mostly from memory, so pardon if there are slight issues.  I assume this is not a secure method, so if you're working with sensitive information, I would look more into the do's and dont's...etc, but - it works fine for our non-sensitive purposes.

Comment: the variable loses its value when i refresh the page. is there a way to change it on the Appmodel? instead of changing the database.php file itself?

Comment: You can use Configure::write in anything throughout Cake (basically), and you can also set the database you'd like to use in the AppModel.  That being said, you can use any of these concepts with session vars too.  I just misunderstood that you needed to retain it across page views.